# What is the difference between mint and freeze authority?

Tags: mint, deploy, burn

When I have an SPL token, I can revoke freeze authority and I can revoke mint. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1):

Each of these two authorities allow for different things:

- freeze authority - can "freeze" the tokens inside a wallet. So the owner of the tokens would not be able to move/transfer/sell them to a different wallet. think of this sort of like one way to create non-transferable tokens (aka soul-bound tokens)
- mint authority - is required to sign a transaction that actually creates new tokens (aka mints new token). So if create a fungible token called TokenX, and initially mint 10 tokens for a total supply of 10. You can later come back and mint new additional tokens into the max supply when this mint authority signs the transaction. raising the total supply of your fungible token